# use jxbrowser , how to get each response

Tags: jxbrowser

jxbrowser 4.4：

browser.getHTML() method only get all the request loaded html.
I want each request return response content.

NetworkDelegate onCompleted method only get each url, how to get each reponse content?
Anybody can show example how to get each response.
Thanks.

```
browser.getContext().setNetworkDelegate(new NetworkDelegate() {
    @Override
    public void onSendHeaders(SendHeadersParams arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onResponseStarted(ResponseStartedParams arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onHeadersReceived(HeadersReceivedParams arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(RequestCompletedParams arg0) {
        System.out.println("onCompleted-----> " + arg0.getURL());
        // this place only get url, how to get each response content?
        // this place only get url, how to get each response content?
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeforeURLRequest(BeforeURLRequestParams arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeforeSendHeaders(BeforeSendHeadersParams arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onBeforeRedirect(BeforeRedirectParams arg0) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onAuthRequired(AuthRequiredParams arg0) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SendHeadersParams, ResponseStartedParams, RequestCompletedParams, etc. provides access to the data for corresponding event. Right now JxBrowser provides only data such as URL, Net Error flags, HTTP request/response headers. It doesn't provide access to the actual response content. Actually, this is what Chromium API provides. Chromium doesn't provide actual response content via network delegate API. The response content can be obtained from cache or web server depending on Chromium's caching algorithm. Unfortunately, right now JxBrowser doesn't integrates with Chromium functionality that obtains response content.